# Expensive Query, how to optimize

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a three tables (Entered_Triplets, Entered_Quads, Values_Contained)  where two of the tables hold historical values. In my third table, I want to mark a column if the entries from the other two tables exist in the third table. However, the current query takes about 4 hours to process and I am unsure how to optimize it. Is there a better way to do this? Values_Contained table has over 22 million rows. While the other two tables have about 400k rows.

```sql
update vc
set vc.TripletsCounted = case when exists(select *
                                          from Entered_Triplets
                                          where TotalCount <> 0
                                            and Number_1 in(vc.Number_1, vc.Number_2, vc.Number_3, vc.Number_4, vc.Number_5)
                                            and Number_2 in(vc.Number_1, vc.Number_2, vc.Number_3, vc.Number_4, vc.Number_5)
                                            and Number_3 in(vc.Number_1, vc.Number_2, vc.Number_3, vc.Number_4, vc.Number_5)) then vc.TripletsCounted + 1
                              else vc.TripletsCounted
                         end
   ,vc.QuadsCounted = case when exists(select *
                                       from Entered_Quads
                                       where TotalCount <> 0
                                       and Number_1 in(vc.Number_1, vc.Number_2, vc.Number_3, vc.Number_4, vc.Number_5)
                                       and Number_2 in(vc.Number_1, vc.Number_2, vc.Number_3, vc.Number_4, vc.Number_5)
                                       and Number_3 in(vc.Number_1, vc.Number_2, vc.Number_3, vc.Number_4, vc.Number_5)
                                       and Number_4 in(vc.Number_1, vc.Number_2, vc.Number_3, vc.Number_4, vc.Number_5)) then vc.QuadsCounted + 1
                           else vc.QuadsCounted
                      end
from Values_Contained vc
```

Comment: I strongly recommend aliasing your objects in those subqueries and qualifying your columns. Syntax like `Number_1 = vc.Number_1` is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Lamu thanks for the suggestion. Any tips to optimize the query? I believe your suggestion is meant to declutter the possibility of calling the wrong columns.

Comment: L a ***r n*** u...

Comment: Honestly, the problem looks like a denormalisation issue to me, due to the fact you have 3 `number` columns in one table, 4 in another, and 5 in another. The problem is less the query and more the design of the database.

Comment: @Larnu that is the way it has to be done. From the data-entry standpoint, you can only enter three values for the blood device and 4 separate values for the urinalysis device. To combine these would not be ideal.

Comment: They shouldn't be combined, they should be separate rows.

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN or your query

Comment: Part of this issue with the long run time is that your `UPDATE` occurs on each of those 22 million rows you have in Values_Contained. Most of those values are probably having their present value written back into them, but limiting the update set to just those rows with changes to Entered_Triplets or Entered_Quads would ease the load tremendously

Comment: You should always be extremely careful to use a `WHERE` clause _any and every_ time you issue an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` because they will operate over the entirety of the table otherwise

Comment: I think that the biggest "easy button" change to make on this is to split it into two `UPDATE`s with filtering conditions to limit the set of rows being updated to just those with either "Triplet" or "Quad" rows. My preference would be to use an `INNER JOIN` but a `WHERE EXISTS` will also outperform the posted version of this

Answer (score 2):

This answer should help you alleviate a great deal of your current performance bottleneck. As mentioned in the comments, there are some notable performance-limiting design decisions reflected in your table structure, but we don't always (ever?) have the luxury of correcting every schema we're forced to use.

This approach performs two separate `UPDATES`, but each of them operates over a much smaller set of rows than your original code. This is achieved by using an `INNER JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause to filter out the rows that will not require a change. As a result, you should observe dramatic reductions in query duration.

On a side note, you will find that reviewing this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and incorporating its guidance will greatly improve your experience when asking questions.

```
UPDATE vc
   SET TripletsCounted = vc.TripletsCounted + 1
  FROM Values_Contained      AS vc
 INNER JOIN Entered_Triplets AS et
    ON et.Number_1 IN (vc.Number_1,
                       vc.Number_2,
                       vc.Number_3,
                       vc.Number_4,
                       vc.Number_5)
       AND Number_2 IN (vc.Number_1,
                        vc.Number_2,
                        vc.Number_3,
                        vc.Number_4,
                        vc.Number_5)
       AND Number_3 IN (vc.Number_1,
                        vc.Number_2,
                        vc.Number_3,
                        vc.Number_4,
                        vc.Number_5)
 WHERE et.TotalCount <> 0;

UPDATE vc
   SET TripletsCounted = vc.TripletsCounted + 1
  FROM Values_Contained  AS vc
 INNER JOIN QuadsCounted AS qc
    ON qc.Number_1 IN (vc.Number_1,
                       vc.Number_2,
                       vc.Number_3,
                       vc.Number_4,
                       vc.Number_5)
       AND Number_2 IN (vc.Number_1,
                        vc.Number_2,
                        vc.Number_3,
                        vc.Number_4,
                        vc.Number_5)
       AND Number_3 IN (vc.Number_1,
                        vc.Number_2,
                        vc.Number_3,
                        vc.Number_4,
                        vc.Number_5)
 WHERE qc.TotalCount <> 0;
```